# Detect prefixes / operators from inside the function

Tags: php, function, operators, prefix

Example:

```
function foo($whatever){
  // ... do stuff here
}

// call the function
+foo(1234);
```

Can I find out from within my function if it was called with `+` (or `-`, `!` etc) ?

Comment: function foo($whatever,$operator){ 
  // ... do stuff here 
} 
 
// call the function 
+foo(1234,'+');

Comment: I know I can add an additional arguments, but I was wondering if I can do it with prefixes. looks nicer

Comment: In what situation would this helpful? If you need the function to do some logic based on how it was called, then pass another argument.

Comment: can you give an example of use?

Comment: well, think of a multipurpose shopping cart function:) +doggie() adds a doggie in the cart, -doggie() removes doggie from cart etc

Comment: @Alex that doesn't make much sense to me, I think most people reading that would expect the operator to be applied to the result of the function instead of affecting what the function does.

Comment: Looks like you need to create your own language... or create methods like addToCart() and removeFromCart, which are rather more intuitive to most coders

Answer (score 3):

The function wasn't called with `+`. The function was called and then the result was used as an operand for `+`.

So no.